# Linq-to-Entities, compare int values in different fields/columns and return max value

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a table with records that have 8 integer values:

```
TableChild:
    Parent    Name    int1    int2    int3    int4    int5    int6    int7    int8
    a         w       1       3       2       0       1       3       4       3
    a         x       4       5       2       5       3       2       4       6
    b         y       5       3       5       3       1       1       3       4
    b         z       4       1       2       4       2       2       4       2
```

I need to find the maximum value for 'x' for example.
I also (separately) need to get the highest value in the whole table for parent 'a' for example.

```
var query = from row in TableChild
            where row.Name == x
            select new 
            {
                Parent = row.Parent,
                Name = row.Name,
                status = GetHighestValueOfRowInTableChild, 
                ...           
            };
```

returns { (a,x,6) }

```
var queryParent = from row in tableParent     
                  where row.Name == a
                  select new 
                  {
                      Parent = row.Name,
                      status = GetHighestValueOfAllChildItemsInTableChild,
                      ...
                  };
```

returns { (a,6) }

I have played around with .Max() and attempted using expressions, but haven't had any luck as I should probably be using multiple joins but can't figure out how they should interact.

Comment: I wanted to normalise these tables for precisely this reason but the designer wants it this way - but yes, I agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array with the values of int{X} properties, an later get the max value of the array

```
var queryParent = from row in tableParent     
                      where row.Name == a
                      select new 
                      {

                         Parent = row.Name,
                         status = 
                         (new int[]{row.int1,row.int2,row.int3,row.int4,
                         row.int5,row.int6,row.int7,row.int8}).Max();
                          ...

                      };
```

Comment: This was precisely the method I was playing around with - I just couldn't get it right. Thanks! I thought there'd be some 'fancy' way of doing it. But this seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're fetching a very large number of records and need to reduce the size of the DB response, it's probably best to just fetch all columns and do the `Max` on the client side.

Comment: I would argue that "*best*" should probably be reworded to "*easiest*".

Comment: And I would argue that as long as the performance is good enough, the easiest solution is usually the best.

Comment: If I were to be fetching a very large number of records, what would you suggest? - Currently mine is a small number of records but I'm thinking that maybe other people might want to know?

Comment: If that were the case, I'd write a stored procedure on the DB end. I doubt that there's a way to do this in LINQ that is both simple and efficient.